# How to support different screens in android

Tags: android, layout, screen

After reading the documentation provided [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), i felt its better to use DP for all the pixels we declare it in layout file, But doing like this work for all different screen sizes.?

For eg: lets take galaxy phones of samsung and xperia neo phone. Galaxy phone is broader in width but xperia is smaller in width. so in this case how android will adjust the layout?. How to handle these kind of senarios

Answer (score 0):

Using dps is basically like designing in inches-  1 dp is 1/160th of an inch.  Android won't adjust anything, it will do things just as you say-  in physical units.  If that means things go off the screen or you have empty space on the screen, Android won't care.

Comment: how to handle these kind of scenarios? where in we have different screen sizes whose width is broader and height is shorter etc.. how to create a single apk which works for all screen sizes

Comment: You test how it looks.  If you don't like how it works, you create a second layout file for those devices, and add it as an override for those screen sizes.  Note that every device will have screen sizes when the width is bigger than the height and vice versa-  landscape and portrait modes.

Comment: At run time, we cant let the android to load those files?. by providing different layout files?. If so in which folder we need to place them?

Comment: Read the link you posted, it tells you all about how to do it.